# I can't find the way to get this simple Jquery/Json task work

Tags: jquery, json

I'm trying to do something to learn the basics of json. I want to use jquery for it. I wrote a simple json file, as you see below; and i want to call it to html page. Could you please tell me what's wrong with my code?
Thank you in advance.

json file

```
{"movies" : [
{"image":"hfgh5.jpg", 
 "description":"Two imprisoned men bond over a number of years, finding solace and eventual redemption through acts of common decency."},

{"image":"fdg.jpg", 
 "description":"The aging patriarch of an organized crime dynasty transfers control of his clandestine empire to his reluctant son."},

{"image":"36frg.jpg", 
 "description":"The lives of two mob hit men, a boxer, a gangster's wife, and a pair of diner bandits intertwine in four tales of violence and redemption."}
]
}
```

JavaScript:

```
   $(document).ready(function () {

       for (i = 0; i < movies.length; i++) {

           $.getJSON('film.json', function () {
               $('.row').html('<img src="' + movies.image[i] + '">');
                $('.row').html('<p>' + movies.description[i] + '</p>');


           });
       }
   });
```

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Why are you doing a `$.getJSON` call *inside* a `for` loop?  You need to put a variable name in the callback's signature: `$.getJSON('film.json', function(data){`.  Inside the callback, `data.movies` will be an array, that's probably where you wanted to loop.

Comment: Maybe you could tell *us* what's wrong with it (what you want it to do & what it does instead). But the three main problems seem to be that 1) you're assuming that `movies` is magically available for you to use directly, which is not so, 2) you're looping through the `movies` array *before* you're loading it from the server and 3)   `.html()` overwrites the existing data so even when you fix the previous problems you'll always overwrite everything every time you call it.

Comment: So it might be better to take a step back and study a good tutorial that explains things from the start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is all mixed up and in the wrong order.  You need to loop over the data *after* getting it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Your callback needs a variable to store the data in
    $.getJSON('film.json', function(data){
        // data is your entire object, data.movies is an array
        for (var i = 0; i < data.movies.length; i++) {
             // .html() will *replace* the HTML, you want to .append()
             $('.row').append('<img src="' + data.movies[i].image + '">');
             $('.row').append('<p>' + datamovies[i].description + '</p>');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but I tried this, and it didn't work. The page is empty again. What should I do?

Comment: Open your browser's devtools and check the console and network tab.  See if there are any errors and see if the AJAX call is running.  You *are* loading jQuery, right?

Comment: CDN of old version of Jquery was the problem. It worked.

Answer (score 0):

Just a few problems, but otherwise off to a good start.

1. you want to put the for loop inside the `getJSON` success callback bc that's when you'll have the movies.
2. you were overriding $('.row') HTML each time, so switched to a simple `innerHTML +=`, and also consolidated the appending of image and description.
3. the `i` in the for loop should be declared with `var` keyword as it's
   not a global.
4. It would also be good to append the generated HTML to an element with an `id`, because presumably you'll have more than one `$('.row')`

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row" id="movies_row"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**jquery:**

```
   $(function() {
       $.getJSON('film.json', function(data) {
           var movies = data.movies;
           for (var i = 0, j = movies.length; i < j; i++) {
              var movie = movies[i];
              $('#movies_row')[0].innerHTML += '<img src="'+movie.image+'"><p>'+movie.description+'</p>');
           }
       });
   });
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {

       $.getJSON('film.json', function () {
         for (i = 0; i < movies.length; i++) {
           $('.row').html('<img src="' + **movies[i].image** + '">');
            $('.row').html('<p>' + **movies[i].description** + '</p>');
          }

       });
});
```

movies is the array and requires the indexer not the image nor description.

also as noted the loop goes inside the getjson not around it